# Symfony 3.2 Doctrine2 ORM storage of complex queries in the form of classes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

Kind time of the day, connoisseurs Symfony Already the third day I study Symfony 3.2 I learned to access several databases and tried a little Doctrine 2

Everything worked out. Prompt please where to me to store a library of requests to a database that I did not have to use repeated requests in various controllers.

If I do not understand explain

There is a controller for example this `src / ParserBundle / EmployeesController.php`

There is a:

```
$Repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ParserBundle:Provider');
$Providers = $repository->findAll();
```

There is a class on queries to the database for example this `src / ParserBundle / Entity / Provider.php`

Then how to make complex queries I can read from the Doctrine 2 documentation, but where can I store them that would not duplicate? And how to access them from the main controllers - is there documentation about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a Doctrine repository, yes there is documentation about it of course: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html

In the controller, you call it the same way as you did before. Your custom repository class will just override the default one.

```
$providers = $repository->myCustomFind();
```

PS: Symfony is written with a **f** not **ph**... :)